# How do I convert my for loop in a function that receives a list input to accommodate that list input and return an output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, hash, list-comprehension

Currently, my issue is that I have created a function that takes in a single hash input that is a hash of a number from 1 to 500000. However, I cannot figure out how to input a list into this function which the for loop will out put the list of the "unhashed" values for me which in this case would be numbers.

So for example:

I put in the hash for

```
"2" = "d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35"
```

and then, I run my code which compares it to my library, and it checks if it is the same to a hashed value in my libary and if it is, it will output 2 in this case.

I am not sure where to start from. I tried changing the password into an empty matrix to house the values, but that did not work.

```py
import hashlib

counter = 1
  #C:\Users\valov\Desktop #location of wordlist file

try:
    sha256_file = open("C:/Users/valov/Desktop/lab3.txt",'r')
except:
    print("\nFile Not Found")
    quit()
#sha256_file = open(r"C:/Users/valov/Desktop/lab3.txt", 'r') #read file

def hash_to_int(hash_list):
    global counter
    #for loop to go through given file and then encode hash
    for password in sha256_file:
        hash_obj = hashlib.sha256(password.strip().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        (counter,password.strip())
        counter += 1
        #check inserted hash against hash from our file, if true, print out value
        if hash_obj == hash_list:
            print(password)
```

However, I cannot make it take in a list. So if I input the hash of 1 and 2 together like this:

```py
hash_to_int(["6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b"
                 "d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35"])
```

it will output [1 2]

Comment: How about just `[hash_to_int(i) for i in your_list]`?

Comment: @KlausD. I am not sure what you mean by this. Where would I put this?